# Get Solana SPL Address from base 58 string

Tags: spl-token, spl, spl-token-program, mint

Hi I have a base58 string for an SPL token address (called a mint in the Solana docs);
This is how I generated this string:

```
    const mint = await createMint(
        connection,
        payer,
        payer.publicKey,
        payer.publicKey,
        9 // We are using 9 to match the CLI decimal default exactly
      );

      //PublicKey {
      // _bn: <BN: f18d4c56c6c9998782580321e8464aea9ffd4452879d5575aa62b856e837c871>>
      //}


      var  mint58 =  mint.toBase58();
      //HFvDm6RsgU6Hxscw2YHhPMmjRVzTEigW1ma61kB9M79i
```

How to go the other way around, i.e. get from the mint58 to the public key in the correct data structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the correct key by calling `new PublicKey(string)`.

The constructor for `PublicKey` takes a number of different types: `number | string | Buffer | Uint8Array | number[]`

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#PublicKeyInitData

```
import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js'

const mint58 = "HFvDm6RsgU6Hxscw2YHhPMmjRVzTEigW1ma61kB9M79i"
const pubkey = new web3.PublicKey(mint58);

console.log(pubkey);
```